# speed up nested loop and call functions in python

Tags: python, function, loops, nested-loops, nested-for-loop

I'm programming a python code and my problem is that this code takes a lot of time and I want to know is it possible to make it faster? I have two lists of tuples as bellow:

```
Similarities = [(1, 1, 1.0),(1, 2, -0.0016),(1, 3, 0.01764),(1, 4, -0.0033),(1, 5, -0.0016),...]
```

and

```
Trust = [(2, 104, 1),(5, 1509, 1),(6, 1192, 1),(7, 1510, 1),(12, 234, 1),(15, 652, 1),...]
```

length of `Similarities = 2274064` and length of `Trust = 37997`
my touples are in format of: `(i,j,value)`

I want to check tuples if i and j are in the range of loop, function return their values to loop and after check, if these values exist or not d will be calculated. And then the amount of d will be appended to a 2D array.

Now I want to run the bellow code:

```
totalDistance=[]
totalSim=[]
for i in range(1642):
    totalDistance.append([])
    totalSim.append([])
    for j in range(1642):
        //search in Trust list to find value of trust i and j
        tr=calcTrustDif(i,j)
        //search in Similarities list to find value of similarity i and j
        pc=calcPccDif(i,j)
        if tr and pc:
            d=math.sqrt(pow(pc,2)+pow(tr,2))
        elif tr and not(pc):
            d=tr
        elif pc and not(tr):
            d=pc
        else:
            d=3
        totalSim[i].append(1-d)
        totalDistance[i].append(d)
def calcTrustDif(i,j):
    
    tr=[t for t in Trust if t[0]== i and t[1]==j]
    if tr:
        return tr[0][2]
    else:
        pass
def calcPccDif(i,j):
    
    pc=[t for t in Similarities if t[0]== i and t[1]==j]
    if pc:
        return 1-pc[0][2]
    else:
        pass
```

I estimated and I found this code will take 82 hours and it is very bad... can anybody help me to reduce run time? I think python has magical features for this situation that I don't know them.

Comment: does it have to be lists? You could probably improve performance quite a bit using numpy array and do the calculations in vectorized fashion.

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to achieve, what problem are you solving. "Run this messy code" is not good enough description.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question.

Comment: Are `(i, j)` in the `Similarities` and `Trust` list ordered?

Comment: @RolandDeschain No, they are not ordered.

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on time complexity and the [**Big O notation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

The reason your code runs so slow is that you are using triply nested `for` loops, which result in a very bad time complexity ~ specifically `O(n*n*(allT+allP))`, where `n = 1642` in your case.

I'd recommend trying to come up with an algorithm where you don't have to iterate through `allP` and `allT` `1642*1642` times. Just choosing a better algorithm can vastly improve the runtime without having to resort to any *"Python magic"*.

Note: you could make it easier for others to understand what you are trying to achieve with your code if you used more meaningful names for your variables. E.g. the meaning of `calcPccDif()`, `allP`, `allT` might be obvious to you, but it does not mean anything to others, and thus makes it difficult for others to read your code. (On the other hand, `totalDistance` is clear and meaningful.)